# Cannot embed multiple animated matplotlib graphs in tkinter window

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, customtkinter

When first clicking the "Live Secondary Mission Graphs" button, the secondary graph data plot is embedded in the GUI and is animated, however two blank primary figures are created, one is the graph created by the `primary` object and the other is the graph created by the `secondary` object. When clicking the "Live Primary Mission Graphs" button afterwards, it reloads the graphs but no new graph is plotted in the GUI, and i get an error message in the terminal saying:

UserWarning: Animation was deleted without rendering anything. This is most likely not intended. To prevent deletion, assign the Animation to a variable, e.g. `anim`, that exists until you output the Animation using `plt.show()` or `anim.save()`.

here is the module used to create the GUI

```
import customtkinter as ctk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from data_processing.primary_graph_data import PrimaryGraphData
from data_processing.secondary_graph_data import SecondaryGraphData

class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry(f"{1100}x{580}")

        self.tabview = ctk.CTkTabview(self, width=1080, height=570)
        self.tabview.pack()
        
        self.tabview.add("Live Primary Mission Graphs")
        self.tabview.add("Live Secondary Mission Graphs")

        #LIVE GRAPHS SETUP
        primary = PrimaryGraphData()
        canvas_primary = FigureCanvasTkAgg(primary.primaryfig, self.tabview.tab("Live Primary Mission Graphs"))
        canvas_primary.draw()
        canvas_primary.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0)

        primary_graphs_button = ctk.CTkButton(self.tabview.tab("Live Primary Mission Graphs"), text="Start Primary Mission Graphs", command=lambda:primary.plot_primary_graphs())
        primary_graphs_button.place(x=850, y=190)

        secondary = SecondaryGraphData()
        canvas_secondary = FigureCanvasTkAgg(secondary.secondaryfig, self.tabview.tab("Live Secondary Mission Graphs"))
        canvas_secondary.draw()
        canvas_secondary.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0)

        secondary_graphs_button = ctk.CTkButton(self.tabview.tab("Live Secondary Mission Graphs"), text="Start Secondary Mission Graphs", command=lambda: secondary.plot_secondary_graphs())
        secondary_graphs_button.place(x=850, y=190)
```

I have tried switching around the order in which the code to display each of the graphs displays, and it only allows me to display the last bit of run code e.g. if the `primary_graphs_button` line is executed after the `secondary_graphs_botton` line, that button will work in displaying the graphs.

the classes I used to crate the matplotlib graphs are below:

```
class PrimaryGraphData():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        
        self.PRIMARYDATASOURCE = "data.csv"
        self.primaryfig, self.primaryaxs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

    def animate(self, i):
        data = pd.read_csv(self.PRIMARYDATASOURCE)
        time = data["Time"]
        temp = data["Temperature"]
        press = data["Pressure"]
        alt = data["Altitude"]

        plt.cla()
        self.primaryaxs[0, 0].plot(time, temp, "tab:orange")
        self.primaryaxs[0, 1].plot(time, press, "tab:green")
        self.primaryaxs[1, 0].plot(alt, temp)
        self.primaryaxs[1, 1].plot(time, alt, "tab:blue")

    def plot_primary_graphs(self):

        ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), func=self.animate, interval=500, frames=50)
        
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show()
```

```
class SecondaryGraphData():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        
        self.SECONDARYDATASOURCE = "data2.csv"
        self.secondaryfig, self.secondaryaxs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

    def secondaryanimate(self, i):
        data = pd.read_csv(self.SECONDARYDATASOURCE)
        time = data["Time"]
        alt = data["Altitude"]
        TVOC = data["TVOC"]
        eCO2 = data["eCO2"]
        H2 = data["H2"]
        Ethanol = data["Ethanol"]

        plt.cla()

        # Plot subplots
        self.secondaryaxs[0, 0].plot(time, TVOC, "tab:green")
        self.secondaryaxs[0, 1].plot(alt, eCO2, "tab:green")
        self.secondaryaxs[1, 0].plot(alt, H2)
        self.secondaryaxs[1, 1].plot(time, Ethanol, "tab:blue")

    def plot_secondary_graphs(self):

        anisecondary = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), func=self.secondaryanimate, interval=500,frames=50)
        
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From talking with a friend, I realised the issue was due to the animating of the graphs being placed inside an object, which required the use of the plt.show() function which was what was creating the blank primary figures, placing the animation of the graphs in functions instead and moving the `canvas_primary = FigureCanvasTkAgg(primary.primaryfig, self.tabview.tab("Live Primary Mission Graphs"))` inside that function as well solved the issue.

Here is the function in it's entirety:

```
def primarygraphdata(primaryview, PRIMARYDATASOURCE):
    
    plt.style.use("dark_background")
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (16, 10)

    # Initialise subplots
    primaryfig, primaryaxs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

    primaryfig.suptitle("Primary Mission Graphs")
    primaryfig.set_facecolor("#2b2b2b")

    primaryaxs[0, 0].set_title("Time vs Temperature")
    primaryaxs[0, 1].set_title("Time vs Pressure")
    primaryaxs[1, 0].set_title("Altitude vs Temperature")
    primaryaxs[1, 1].set_title("Time vs Altitude")

    def primaryanimate(i):
        data = pd.read_csv(PRIMARYDATASOURCE)
        time = data["Time"]
        temp = data["Temperature"]
        press = data["Pressure"]
        alt = data["Altitude"]

        plt.cla()
        # Plot subplots
        primaryaxs[0, 0].plot(time, temp, "tab:orange")
        primaryaxs[0, 1].plot(time, press, "tab:green")
        primaryaxs[1, 0].plot(alt, temp)
        primaryaxs[1, 1].plot(time, alt, "tab:blue")

    aniprimary = FuncAnimation(primaryfig, func=primaryanimate, interval=500, frames=50, cache_frame_data=False)
   
    plt.tight_layout()
    canvas_primary = FigureCanvasTkAgg(primaryfig, primaryview)
    canvas_primary.draw()
    canvas_primary.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=0)
```